# $G$ expressed as a function of $c$?

Tags: speed-of-light, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants, escape-velocity

The escape velocity for a given mass $M$ and a given radius $r$ is given by:

$v_e = \sqrt{ \frac{2 G M}{r} }$

With $M$ = 25 kg and $r$ = 1/$c$ we have:

$v_e = 1.0001917061 \approx 1$

Can we express $G$ as a function of $c$ ? Like:

$G \approx \frac{1}{2 M c} = \frac{1}{50 c} = 6.67128190396\times10^{-11}$

Comment: What does $c$ stand for?

Comment: $c$ is the speed of light. $r=1/c$ is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot.  The constants $G$ and $c$ have different units, so $G$ cannot be equal to $c$ times some dimensionless constant as in your question.

From a [metrology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrology) perspective, $c$ defines how we relate time and length, while $G$ involves the definition of mass.  In the SI system of units, $c$ is defined exactly. As of a couple of years ago, the definition of mass is hiding in an exact definition of $\hbar$.  The ratio $G/\hbar c$ (which has units of $(\text{mass})^{-2}$) is only known to about five significant figures.

Note that in your question, you set $r=1/c$. That’s not allowed either, for dimensional reasons: the numbers are meaningless without their attached units.  Imagine saying “how tall is that tree?” and getting the answer “twenty-five hours per mile.” A length is a different creature from an inverse speed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rob. Yes, I known that r=/c is way over the edge and I should have done more thinking on this before asking this question.

Comment: 'How tall is that tree?' A.: 'Six potatoes!'

Comment: @Gert [On the apple as a length unit in literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Smurfs)

Comment: @rob Hahaha, very drole!